# How To make Td style visible by getting value from session variable from another page my code attached PHP HTML?

Tags: php, html, css, validation

i wanna know to make my td tag style visible an getting value from another php page in the form of session varialbe as my code is define under,

on else condition fron php page i am setting session variable and redirecting to another page as,

```
else {
session_start();
$_SESSION['Validation'] = 'on';
header("Location: index.html");
}
```

after then on index.html page in between table tag i am using this script as,

```
<?php
session_start();
$foo = $_GET['Validation'];
echo $foo;
?>
<tr><td colspan=2><font face="verdana,arial" size="-1" color="red"       style="visibility:hidden">Wrong username or Password</font></td></tr>
```

how to make td tag style vissible true and it remain hidden if session variable do not get any value ????

Hopes to listen from you ...

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use a simple `if... then... else` condition and make use of your $_SESSION variable to switch those conditions. Create a new variable to hold your current style e.g. `$tdStyle = "visibility: hidden;"` or `$tdStyle = "visibility: visible;"` for hiding/showing your td, respectively.

HTML/PHP CODE: [EDIT]

```
<?php
  ...
  if ($_SESSION['Validation'] == "on") {
     $tdStyle = "visibility: visible;";
  } else  {
     $tdStyle = "visibility: hidden;";
  }
  ...
?>
...
<tr><td style="<?php echo $tdStyle; ?>">Wrong username or Password</td></tr>
...
```

EDIT: Use `index.php` not `index.html` when embedding PHP codes in HTML or your php code will be treated as plain text/html

```
header("Location: index.php");

NOT

header("Location: index.html");
```

Comment: i am not getting it can you give its example ?

Comment: @SyedRaza also, do not use `index.html`, instead use `index.php` since you are coding `PHP` inside your `HTML` code. Otherwise, the embedded PHP codes will never be interpreted by the PHP engine.

Comment: humm tahts why i am not getting after doing that as you told me ok i try it

Comment: i am getting error when i first load this page with out redirecting to it from any other page "undefined variable $-session "??

Comment: Did you start your PHP page with `<?php session_start()` ? If you are using sessions and session variables [e.g. `$_SESSION['foo_bar']`], always use `session_start();` at the very beginning of your php page.

Comment: yes i did it and solve it by using session_start() then i will have to null this variable for the next time ??

Comment: @SyedRaza yes, set it to NULL to "hide" your td.

Comment: @SyedRaza glad to be of help.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
session_start();
$foo = $_GET['Validation'];
echo $foo;
?>
<tr>
<td colspan=2>
<font face="verdana,arial" size="-1" color="red" <?php
if (isset($_SESSION['style_visible'])) {
  echo 'style="visibility:visible"';
} else {
  echo 'style="visibility:hidden"';
}
?>
>Wrong username or Password</font></td></tr>
```

But I think it's wrong

1st Validation

```
<?php

// make validation
$errors = array();
// if error fill $errors

// store errors in sessions
if (count($errors) > 0) $_SESSION['errors'] = $errors;
```

2nd form

```
<?php
session_start();

// show errors
if (isset($_SESSION['errors'])) {
    foreach ($_SESSION['errors'] as $error) {
      echo '<tr><td>'.$error.'</td></tr>';
    }
}

?>
```